# ¿Como puedo conectarme a una base de datos web desde mi PC?

Tags: php, mysql

Bueno este caso no se me habia presentado hasta ahora, resulta que tengo un conocido que compro un dominio (de el) y me ha separado un espacio (por asi decirlo) en su servidor. Tengo mi web alojada, recien voy a comenzar a desarrollar lo que viene siendo las entradas (ya entra la base de datos).

El problema es que desconosco como se podria conectar a ese servidor. No soy muy experimentado en eso del desarrollo web como podran notar.

¿Con que programa o como puedo conectarme a dicho servidor con estos datos?
Tengo: Direccion IP del server, usuario, contraseña.

Pense en instalar wampserver y phpmyadmin, pero veo que solo sirve de local (a menos que ese sea la solucion y su configuracion cambie...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las conexiones remotas dependen de que de ambas partes sean generosas al momento de trabajar, me explico. En el lado del servidor donde se encuentra la BD que necesitas acceder debe permitir conexiones remotas, por lo que normalmente se tiene que configurar que permita la IP de computador desde el cual deseas acceder. Bien, ahora por el lado tuyo, o del cliente remoto, lo que necesitas es acceder mediante algún manejador. Te muestro una imagen con Query Browser:

[image: Ejemplo]

Teniendo los datos que dices tener, puedes acceder sin problemas. Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias! resulta que ahora no necesito descargarme eso ya que descontinuaron MySQLQueryBrowser, MySqlWorkBench lo tiene incluido ahora! mil gracias!

Comment: Por nada, solo era de ejemplo :). Workbench tiene una interfaz parecida al inicio.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes conectarte con PHP a bases de datos tanto locales como externas sin problemas, únicamente indicando la dirección IP de la base de datos (y en algunos casos el puerto). El problema real que vas a afrontar es el de indicarle a la base de datos que acepte conexiones de usuarios remotos (usualmente las bases de datos de servidores compartidos restringen el acceso a únicamente usuarios locales).

Como mencionas, puedes utilizar un programa como WAMP para tener un servidor local (Apache+PHP) y desde ahí correr el código PHP el cual se conectará a la base de datos remota. Si eliges esta opción, es probable que tengas que mandar un ticket al soporte del servidor (si es que el servidor ofrece soporte para estos casos) pidiendo que habiliten la conexión de usuarios remotos a la base de datos (probablemente te pidan tu IP para únicamente desbloquear la conexión desde tu IP y no para usuarios remotos en general).

La otra opción (y más recomendable) es trabajar directamente en el servidor remoto. Es decir, subir los archivos PHP en aquél servidor y realizar la programación ahí. Esto da la ventaja de que estarás conectándote a la base de datos como usuario local (pues el script PHP que subas estará en el mismo servidor remoto que la base de datos).

Puedes ver un pequeño artículo que habla sobre cómo conectarse a una base de datos para sacar información:

http://blog.aulaformativa.com/conectar-php-con-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

Te comparto una clase para realizar la conexión a la base de datos, esta conexión se realiza por medio de [php](/questions/tagged/php):

```
<?php

  # Clase conexion base de datos Mysqli
  # Bases de datos Mysql en php
  # PHP 5.0



class MySQL
{
  $conexion;
  $host     = "ipDelHost";
  $user     = "Usuario";
  $password = "Contrasena"
  $dbname = "NombreBaseDeDatos";

  function MySQL()
  {

  if(!isset($this->conexion))
    {
        $this->conexion = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password);
      if (!$this->conexion) {
        die('error en la conexion: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno);
        exit();
      }

         mysqli_select_db($this->conexion,$this->dbname) or die("error en la conexion de base de datos: ".mysql_error());
    }
  }
/* retornará un objeto (mysqli_result) con el resultado de la consulta */
 function consultar($query)
 {
    mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
    $resultado = mysqli_query($query,$this->conexion);
    if(!$resultado)
    {
            echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
        exit();
    }
  return $resultado; 
  }
/* retornará "true" si el registro es exitoso */
  function registro($query)
  {
      $resultado = mysqli_query($query,$this->conexion);
    if(!$resultado)
    {
            echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_query();
        exit;
    }
    return $resultado; 
  }

 /* retornará un array con los datos de la consulta*/
 function fetch_array($query)
 { 
    return mysqli_fetch_array($query);
 }

/* Retorna el número de filas del resultado. */
 function num_rows($query)
 { 
     return mysqli_num_rows($query);
 }

 /* Retorna un array de cadenas que se corresponde con la fila obtenida (como una matrix) $fila[0], $fila[1]*/
 function fetch_row($query)
 { 
     return mysql_fetch_row($query);
 }

 /* Devuelve un array asociativo de strings que representa a la fila obtenida del conjunto de resultados, donde cada clave 
    del array representa el nombre de una de las columnas de éste; o NULL si no hubieran más filas en dicho conjunto de resultados.

    Si dos o más columnas del resultado tienen el mismo nombre de campo, la última columna tomará precedencia. Para acceder a la/s otra/s 
    columna/s con el mismo nombre, es necesario acceder al resultado ya sea usando los índices numéricos mediante mysqli_fetch_row(), 
    ya sea añadiéndole alias a los campos.

    Ejemplo

    $consulta = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50,5";

    # obtener array asociativo 

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
    }
  */
 function fetch_assoc($consulta)
 { 
     return mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta);
 } 

}
```

para usarla creas el objeto de la clase y llamas la función que necesites enviando la consulta, allí te dice que retorna cada función, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
<?php
/* llamas la pagina donde esta la clase de conexión */
require_once 'MySQL.php';

/* creas el objeto de la clase */
$mysql = new MySQL();
/* realizas la conexión */
$mysql->MySQL();

$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50,5";
/* realizas la consulta */
$mysql->consultar($query)
```

Espero te sirva